# Chrome returns "Too many redirects" for some users on my PHP website

Tags: php, session, redirect

Some users of my website claim that they are getting a "TOO MANY REDIRECTS" error when they browse my website, but that the issue is partially resolved if they switch browsers.

In any case, I'm try to determine where exactly the loop is being caused. Here's my (modified for StackOverflow) source code:

**configuration.php** (which is included at the top of every PHP page)

```
...
require_once('database.php'); // For PDO connect

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['site_email']))
{
    header('Location: login.php', true, 302);
    die();
}
else
{
    // Update user attributes from database
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM site_users WHERE email = :email');
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_SESSION['site_email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $_SESSION['site_user'] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this_user = $_SESSION['site_user'];
}

...
```

**login.php**

```
...

require_once('database.php'); // For PDO connect

session_start();

// Redirect user if already logged in
if (isset($_SESSION['site_email']))
{
    header('Location: ./', true, 302);
    die();
}

// If the user wanted to login
if (isset($_POST['fm-login']))
{
    // Check if the specified user exists
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM site_users WHERE email LIKE :email');
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['fm-login-email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // If they exist, define session variables and redirect user to the homepage
    if ($result && password_verify($_POST['fm-login-pass'], $result['pass_hash']))
    {
        unset($result['pass_hash']);
        $_SESSION['site_user'] = $result;
        $_SESSION['site_email'] = $_POST['fm-login-email'];
        header('Location: index.php', true, 302);
        die();
    }
    else
    {
        // Bad password error-handling code here
    }
}

...
```

Anyways, was wondering if the StackOverflow community could help me determine why people are randomly logged out of the site or why they might see a "TOO MANY REDIRECTS" error from this logic.

Comment: First of all you have to add session_start() at first then add rest code.

Comment: Make sure configuration.php is not included at the top of login.php

Comment: Is it just me or `if (isset($_SESSION['site_email'])) {   header('Location: ./', true, 302); }` would redirect the user to the same page?